# Angular 7: get access to component methods via router

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm sorry in advance if it's a duplicate of someone question, however I can't find solution for my problem.

I need to get access to component's methods via router tree. I know that common practice is to tie functionality via services, but I'm operating with a `ViewContainerRef` and `ElementRef` which need to provide from component that I need access to.

I have a parent component with some method. When I call it I need to call a method down to the roter tree.

parent.component.ts

```
export class ParentComponent {

    childComponent: ChildComponent;

    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(data => {
            this.childComponent = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.component;
            this.childComponent.someMethod() // not working
        });
    }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
export class ChildComponent {

    constructor() { }

    someMethod() {
        console.log('Method Called');
    }
}
```

I also tried to use `ViewChild` but `ChildComponent` is not a part of parent so it always `undefined`. How can I get acess to ChildComponent method?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can instantiate a component using the `ComponentFactoryResolver` (`@angular/core`) and invoke its public methods.

```
export class ParentComponent {

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(data => {

       const child = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.component;

       // ... validations 

       const cfactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(<any>child);

       console.log(cfactory.componentType.prototype['someMethod']());

    });
  }
}
```

This is however,  a straight up hack.
There must be a better way to achieve whatever it is you're trying to achieve.